# How do I store my Time the same way as my Date in my string?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to store the users entered time in a string and also get the correct output format in the listview. Now when a users enters it's time. The time gets stored on the listview like this: "00:00:00", I just want hour and minute, not second.

When I use my date it all works fine, I store the string and I can find it on other pages and there I bind it to my xaml.

This is how my date looks and it is working fine:
App.ourDates (my global string), selectedDate (my datepicker x:name)

```
App.ourDates = selectedDate.Date.ToString("ddd, d:e MMMM");

Navigation.PushAsync (new StartPage (App.ourDates));
```

And the page the info gets too;
XAML:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding ourSelectedDate, StringFormat='{0:d, d:e MM}'}" FontSize = "14" TextColor = "Black" 
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds = "0.51, 0.2, 0.15 , 0.5"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags = "All"   />
```

So i store it via a public class on the codepage.

It works. When I use the same method for time it does not seem to work, this is my code:
App.ourStartTime (my global string), selectTimeStart (my timepicker x:name).

```
App.ourStartTime =  selectTimeStart.Time.ToString ("t");
Navigation.PushAsync (new StartPage (App.ourStartTime));
```

XAML:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding ourSelectedTimeStart, StringFormat = '{0:H:e M}'}" Font = "14" TextColor = "#BE5869" YAlign = "Center" 
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds = "0.72, 0.8, 0.4 , 0.5"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags = "All" />
```

so it does not work, the first problem i get is that the app.ourStartTime does not store the info for some weird reason, and then when It gets put in the listview it shows like this "00:00:00", I want it to be 00:00.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also specify a fosrmat for the time conversion

`App.ourStartTime =  selectTimeStart.Time.ToString ("HH:mm");`

Comment: Is it possible tgat your variable selectTimeStart does not contain a valid time https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I cant even enter the page where i want to "create" the time. If i use this code: selectTimeStart.Format = "HH:mm"; and when i push it ::
selectTimeStart.Time.ToString(), then it works. but i want to store it so i can reach it everywhere

Comment: What is the type of your properties Date and Time? Do you overwrite ToString for any of them?